# Connecting points with closed sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a connected open set in an arbitrary topology. Let $x,y \in A$. Is there always a connected closed $B \subseteq A: x,y \in B$? If not, is it true under some reasonably weak additional assumptions (like, for instance, axioms of separation)?

Comment: not without a separation axiom. Take the real line with basic open sets of the form  $[a,\infty)$. Then $[a,\infty)$ is open and connected, but contains no closed sets whatsoever (connected or not) apart from the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete answer but shows that separation axioms are not enough, and, if the answer is to be positive, one must also assume the space is locally connected.

Take $X$ to be the closed topologist's sine curve, that is the graph of $\sin\frac1x$ for $0<x\le1$ together with the closed vertical line segment between points $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$. Let $A=X\setminus\{(0,\pm1)\}$. Then $A$ is open in $X$ and connected. Let $x=(0,0)$ and $y=(\frac1\pi,0)$. A closed subset $B$ of $A$ will have to miss some neighborhoods of $(0,-1)$ and $(0,1)$, and hence cannot be connected, if it contains both $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the space $S =\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{ \emptyset, \{0\}, S\}$. Let $A = \{0\}$ and $x=y=0$. Then $A$ is open and connected but does not contain any nonempty closed subset.

Comment: OP: "If not, is it true under some reasonably weak additional assumptions (like, for instance, axioms of separation)?"

Answer (score 0):

Assume $A$ is a proper non-empty subset of $X$ where $X$ is endowed with the topology $\{\emptyset,A,X\}$. Then clearly $A$ is connected, but the only closed subset is the empty set. Clearly $x,y\notin\emptyset$.

Comment: $\{x,y\}$ does us no good since it's not connected.

Comment: OP: "If not, is it true under some reasonably weak additional assumptions (like, for instance, axioms of separation)?" How does $A$ from the first part (not Hausdorff) of your answer relate to $A$ from the second part (Hausdorff)?

Comment: @MichałZapała: Oops, I will correct that.

Comment: @Mirko: Those two parts are unrelated and (were supposed to) answer the two different questions. The only thing both $A$ have in common is that they are connected open sets.